New Google Chrome version doesn't accept `--password-store=basic` any more, how to prevent "Passwords and Keys" dialog from appearing?
The system in question is autologged in, so to prevent Google Chrome from popping up the Seahorse dialog box, I changed the shortcut to provide the --password-store=basic option per this fine q&a: Chrome asks for password to unlock keyring on startup
This has worked for years, but it no longer works, starting with Chrome version 131.0.6778.69
Is there a new workaround?

Have you tried using --password-store=gnome or putting the Keyring Password to Blank in SeaHorse ?

@Saxtheowl It looks like the gnome option works. If you care to post an answer, I'll accept it with thanks.

One solution would be to set the --password-store=gnome Option instead, it will tell Chrome that it has to use the gnome Keyring without prompting for a password.

Start normally as before or with --password-store=basic,
but delete the directory ~/.local/share/keyrings/.
